# Windows Domain - Time period until User needs to re-authenticate to the Domain?

Tags: windows, domain, time

I run a Windows Domain (Server 2016) and was wondering how long is the default time that a user can still log in to his computer without having a connection to the domain controller?

If the user is on holiday for example. How long is he still able to log in before he gets an error that the DC is not available or something like that?

And also, is there a way to increase the time before this happens?

Thanks for your answers!!

Comment: By default, once the user has logged onto the computer one time they can log onto it forever without being connected to the corporate network or having connectivity to the Domain Controller. - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj852209(v=ws.11).aspx

Comment: We have people go off on maternity leave with their laptops, and they don't stop letting them log in (even if their password has expired on the domain) - this is often over 1 year away. Hope that helps.